# Calling different Javascript functions in HTML event with different arguments

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have an html pulldown list which contains the items 'Hello' and 'Goodbye'.

What I want do is call javascript functions depending on what the user selects from the pulldown list, a different function will be called depending on the value selected.  I also want to pass in the value of the pulldown list item into the onchange event function parameter.

I have declared the html control like this:

```
<select name="hellobye" id="hellobye" class="pulldown" onchange="sayHello or SayGoodbye(*PULLDOWN SELECTED ITEM TEXT HERE*);"></select>
```

my javascript functions are:

```
function sayHello(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}

function sayGoodbye(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}
```

Please can I have some advice.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this.value` in the onchange.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function sayHello(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}

function sayGoodbye(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}

function say()
{
 var pulldown = document.getElementById("hellobye");
 var selectedValue = pulldown.options[pulldown.selectedIndex].value;

 if(selectedValue == helloMsgValue)
 {
  sayHelo(msg);
 }
 else
 {
   sayGoodbye(msg)
 }
}

<select name="hellobye" id="hellobye" class="pulldown" onchange="say();"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to pass the message to the functions, then why not just have one function `say`:

```
function say(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}
```

Then JavaScript in HTML like this:

```
<select name="hellobye" id="hellobye" class="pulldown" onchange="say(this.value == 'hello' ? 'Hello there' : 'Goodbye to you');">
  <option value="hello">hello</option>
  <option value="goodbye">goodbye</option>
</select>
```

Which uses the ternary operator to decide to send hello or goodbye message.

```
statement to test ? execute if true : execute if false
```

Addition:

If you need to keep your seperate functions, then this should work

```
<select name="hellobye" id="hellobye" class="pulldown" onchange="this.value == 'hello' ? sayHello('Hello there') : sayGoodbye('Goodbye to you') ;">
  <option value="hello">hello</option>
  <option value="goodbye">goodbye</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `this.value` you can capture the selection value and use it in a single function with, perhaps, a `switch()` statement:

```
function sayAnything(){
  switch(this.value){
    case 'goodbye': alert('I said goodbye!');
    case 'hello' : alert('I said hello!');
    default: alert('Im not sure what I said!');
  }
}
```

That would work well if you have a finite and managable list of select options, if you don't then you might look assigning functionality once the select is rendered instead of per-element, eg:

```
<select id="list">
  <options*many value="..." />
</select>

Y.one('#list').children().on('click', function(){
  sayAnything(this.value);
});
```

You'll have to put a test for selectedIndex in there somewhere, but the general idea would be to make the sayAnything() call a common one, and the value of the selected option pipe through to that common method call.